# Do diamagnetic material exhibit induction?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance, magnetics

Silly question perhaps, but do metals with the property of diamagnetism also exhibit  inductance? Would a fluctuating magnetic field induce a current in a diamagnetic metal?

Comment: I seem to have thrown the wrong end of the stick into the forum. Feel free to downvote /+:

What I mean to ask is whether a metal detector (I understand it works on the principle of induction) would be capable of detecting a metal if the metal were strongly diamagnetic

Comment: It's nothing to do with electronic design, and should be closed.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

Diamagnetism in ordinary materials (not supercondutors) is a relatively weak effect.  Whether a current is induced in a material by a changing magnetic field depends on the material's conductivity.  The diamagnetism will appose the external magnetic field somewhat, but since this effect is weak the magnetic field will still penetrate and therefore cause a current if the material is capable of conducting a current.  Note that copper is a diamagnetic material.

Superconductors exihibit what appears to be strong diamagnetism from the outside point of view, but they actually do this precisely because the change in the external magnetic field will cause a current.  Since the superconductor has essentially 0 resistivity, that current continues to circulate instead of die down like it would in ordinary materials.  As a result, the superconductor builds up a reverse magnetic field to the applied field, acting like a strong diamagnet.  In actuality it is acting like a perfect coil.

Comment: Let me rephrase parts of your answer, in an attempt to verify that I understand what you're saying...  If there was a perfect diamagnetic material (not a superconductor) then it wouldn't be inductive.  But since there are no perfectly diamagnetic materials, they will all exhibit some amount of inductance.  A superconductor, is more like a perfect inductor/coil and thus appears to be diamagnetic when in fact it is not.  Is that all correct?

Comment: I'm not totally sure about the inductive part, but otherwise yes that sounds right.  If there were a perfect diamagnetic material it would fully appose the external magnetic field, but I'm not totally sure what that would do to the apparent inductance of a inductor if the diamagnetic material were brought into its field.

Comment: Olin needs to get a StackExhange award!  This man's knowledge of EE is scary!